# Term Added in Taxonomy not available for selection when creating a new product

Tags: magento, drupal, taxonomy

I added a term to a taxonomy list. The taxonomy list is entitled "In Stock Colors" and I added "Gray" to that list.

I need that option to be available when I am creating a new product, so that when I add the product to the Magento catalog, I can select "Gray" as an available In Stock Color.

However, although the term displays in the taxonomy list, it does not display when attempting to create a new product.

How can I make sure that Gray shows up as an available in stock color when adding a new product?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why it won't show up for that product.  The primary things to look at are:

- Make sure the given category is a sub category under the root
  category for that particular store
- make sure the "Is Active" flag for the category is set to "Yes"
- Flush the cache, the new category might not be cached yet
- If that doesn't work re-index the categories